# How to maximise unity webapps?

Tags: webapps

Is there a setting to allow unity webapps to run maximised rather than in a window.
I'm not talking about the full screen F11 mode, but simply maximised to full.

Specifically, my gmail webapp keeps opening in a window I have to keep maximising each time I open it to use easily.

Answer (score 0):

Basically use: webapp-container --maximized

From terminal:

```
$ webapp-container https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox --app-id=comgooglemail --maximized
```

Or create ~/.local/share/applications/comgooglemail.desktop with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gmail Inbox
Name[nl]=Gmail Postvak IN
Exec=webapp-container https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox --app-id=comgooglemail --maximized --user-agent-string='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'
Icon=/home/username/comgooglemail.png
Type=Application
Actions=compose;starred;contacts
StartupWMClass=comgooglemail
OnlyShowIn=Unity

[Desktop Action compose]
Name=Compose
Name[nl]=Opstellen
Exec=webapp-container https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new

[Desktop Action starred]
Name=Starred
Name[nl]=Met ster
Exec=webapp-container https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#starred

[Desktop Action contacts]
Name=Contacts
Name[nl]=Contacten
Exec=webapp-container https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts
```

Now open the Unity dash and type gmail to open the comgooglemail webapp.
This also offers quicklists (visible when right clicking the icon) for Compose, Starred and Contacts.
Search online for an icon (minimum 48x48 pixels) and save it to ~/comgooglemail.png